# Bootstrap: Column elements overflowing on other columns

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap

I have a problem where I use a `class=justify-content-md-center` row with 3 columns inside. The columns are `class='col-auto`. For some reason where I have a few more elements in one of the columns it overflows in the other columns rather than spacing nicely. Here is the code from the console.

```
<div class="justify-content-md-center row">
    <div class="col-md-auto">
        <div class="childAdd addElement elRow" id="i325487081">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
        <div class="popElements popPos elRow" draggable="true"><span>Condition</span>
            <div class="deleteB">X</div>
        </div>
        <div class="justify-content-md-center row">
            <div class="col-md-auto">
                <div class="childAdd addElement elRow" id="i348888406">+</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-auto">
                <div class="childAdd addElement elRow" id="i604066558">+</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-auto">
                <div class="popElements popPos elRow" draggable="true"><span>Sender</span>
                    <div class="deleteB">X</div>
                </div>
                <div class="justify-content-md-center row">
                    <div class="col-md-auto">
                        <div class="childAdd addElement elRow" id="i706392105">+</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
        <div class="childAdd addElement elRow" id="i442852183">+</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the picture for the code above. Note that thats the code for the row containing the 3 columns that are not spaced well.

[image]

Comment: add your code please

Comment: I've now realised that I was using `[class*="col-"] {
  padding: 0 !important;
}` and now it doens't do that anymore but there is padding between the elements which still I don't want. How do I go around that?

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle or code-pen?